# how to Link Libraries in xcode?

Tags: react-native, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension, xcode14.3, target-link-libraries

how can I add a library in Xcode's target `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases`?

> ```
>  "react": "18.2.0",
>  "react-native": "0.71.8",
>  "xcode": "14.3"
> ```

when I add libReact-RCTText.a to `Link Binary With Libraries`, it was throwing error:

```
Library not found for -lReact-RCTText
```

any help will be appreciated.